# Local admin account in Windows 2016 server has limited functionality

Tags: windows-server-2016

I have a Windows 2016 Standard server I created a couple months ago and then joined it to a new AD I created.  Since then when I log in as the local administrator, I'm unable to open the Action Center, nor can I left-click on the Windows start icon (no response), nor is the search icon functional.  This feels like an AD screwup on my part somehow but I'm not sure what I would have done.  Admittedly my skillset as an AD administrator is at the bottom of the barrel.

Any suggestions on how to diagnose this?  Most of the research I've done concerns other issues that don't appear to be relevant to this one.

I do see a number of errors in the Application event log (Cortana can't start, ShellExperienceHost can't start, etc.).

Thanks!

--Ben

Comment: I'm hard pressed to think of a setting that would prevent you from left clicking the Start button. It sounds to me like the machine is borked rather than an AD problem.

Comment: Agreed, local administrator if logged in should be able to correctly alter anything.

Comment: Sorry, wasn't clear.  The local admin has no issues; the domain admin does.